# Where did these upvotes go?

Tags: support, voting, reputation, up-votes

Just a question for curiosity's sake... I don't really care about the 'points' but it does seem odd.

I noticed that I had a notification under the Recent Achievements section, so I clicked on the icon... It says I got two upvotes on a certain question.

Later while perusing the Questions page, I saw that someone else had given an answer to the same question, so I went to look at it (I learn here just as much if not more than I teach)...

And there I see that my answer has no votes whatsoever (I just got to 1,000 points so I can see votes now).

These two screenshots contradict each other:

[image: Upvotes there]

[image: Upvotes not there anymore]

Anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had gotten two upvotes, the reputation notifier would be at +20, as you only get 10 points per upvote. Instead you got 2 reputation for [suggesting an edit to the question that was approved](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/66106). You can see this (and other details on your reputation) [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/94601/bang?tab=reputation).

Comment: Ah it was two points, not two votes... Gotcha. I feel dumb now! Still learning the ins and outs. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Note that the +2 rep per edit will stop after you reach 2k reputation